Finally construct for loop?
I have a number of loops that needs to have a update function run after they finish, except of course if the collection is empty.
This leads to loops like the example below.
I know the if statement could just be on the Update() call only, but I was wondering if there is a construct like finally that works with loops in C#?
if (myList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Item it in myList)
    {
        it.Delete();
    }
    myList.Update();
}

I imagine something looking like this:
foreach (Item it in myList)
{
    it.Delete();
}
finally 
{ 
    myList.Update(); 
}



"if there is a construct like finally that works with loops in C#" - can you scribble down what that's supposed to look like? FWIW, I would scrap that if and add a check inside Update() to return early on an empty collection.

Thanks for the suggestion, I've added an example. Unfortunately the update function is beyond my control, otherwise that was a much faster and easier thing to do.

How is adding a finally block after the loop different from just having the enclosed block after the loop. There's nothing intrinsic to looping that would prevent execution of any subsequent lines!

After Edit: That looks like it would do the opposite of that "IsEmpty" check : "finally" in try/catch is supposed to execute regardless of an exception. So the equivalent here would be to Update regardless of the number of elements? That ddoesn't seem to be what you want?

If code duplication is your concern, I'd just create an extension method that encapsulates this.

Just stick the if around the call to update! If myList is empty then the foreach will be "skipped". Simple

^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/NYgpNc or even more generic: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kctwpa

@Fildor you are 100% correct, what I was thinking about was definitely NOT a finally statement. Luckily the example you asked for cleared up what I was actually asking about.

You could write an extension method:
public static void IterateWithFinalAction<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, Action<T> foreachAction, Action finalAction)
{
   if(collection.Count == 0)
   {
      return;
   }

   foreach(var item in collection)
   {
      foreachAction.Invoke(item);
   }
   finalAction.Invoke();
}

Usage is
myList.IterateWithFinalAction(x => x.Delete(), () => myList.Update());

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q0wcyp

I'd reverse that if check, so you can simply bail-out early on an empty collection and you spare yourself from one level of indentation.

If you wanted to extend this to work with IEnumerable<T> you could loop and set an anyItems boolean inside the loop and then outside the loop do if (anyItems) finalAction();

We can rely on c# having foreach call IEnumerator.Dispose() on our behalf to get our finally.
To simplify things we could create an extension method on IEnumerable<T> - AfterIteration (classic finally) - it will always execute even if there are exceptions thrown, but to OP's requirement only if we actually got to iterate (1 item at least).
I think we could also make use of another method AfterFullIteration which triggers the action when the whole enumerable was iterated and there were no exceptions (and we didn't break at some point)
EDIT: Since the use case is foreach we can implement IEnumerable/IEnumerator-like struct types for the implementation and save ourselves a bit of overhead and make things a bit cleaner. We just have to implement IDisposable for the Enumerator struct, so the compiler will invoke Dispose().
public static class Extensions {

    public static AfterIterationAction<T> AfterIteration<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action action) {
        return new AfterIterationAction<T>(enumerable, action, false);
    }

    public static AfterIterationAction<T> AfterFullIteration<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action action) {
        return new AfterIterationAction<T>(enumerable, action, true);
    }

    // TODO: Thread-safety?
    public struct AfterIterationAction<T>
    (IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action action,
    bool fullIterationRequired) {

        public Enumerator GetEnumerator() => new Enumerator(enumerable.GetEnumerator(), action, fullIterationRequired);

        public struct Enumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, Action action,
        bool onlyForFullSuccesfulIteration) : IDisposable {

            bool started;
            bool finished;
            
            public T Current => enumerator.Current;

            public bool MoveNext() {
                var result = enumerator.MoveNext();
                if (!started && result == true) {
                    started = true;
                } else if (started && result == false) {
                    finished = true;
                }
                return result;
            }

            public void Dispose() {
                if (onlyForFullSuccesfulIteration) {
                    if (finished) action();
                } else {
                    if (started) action();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

So various use cases with comments in the code:
Console.WriteLine("---AfterIteration: Empty Iteration---");
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = new List<int>();
// empty iteration
foreach (var element in enumerable
  .AfterIteration(() => Console.WriteLine("foo"))) {
    Console.WriteLine(element);
} // nothing will be printed because it's empty

Console.WriteLine("-------");

Console.WriteLine("---AfterIteration: No break, nor exception---");
enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
foreach (var element in enumerable
        .AfterIteration(() => Console.WriteLine("foo"))) {
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
// 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, foo
Console.WriteLine("-------");

Console.WriteLine("---AfterIteration: We break ---");
foreach (var element in enumerable
    .AfterIteration(() => Console.WriteLine("foo"))) {
    if (element == 3) {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
// 1, 2, foo
Console.WriteLine("-------");

Console.WriteLine("---AfterIteration: Exception ---");
try {
    // incomplete iteration with exception
    foreach (var element in enumerable
        .AfterIteration(() => Console.WriteLine("foo"))) {
        if (element == 3) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
    // 1, 2, foo
} catch { }
Console.WriteLine("-------");

Console.WriteLine("---AfterFullIteration: Exception ---");
try {
    // incomplete iteration with exception
    foreach (var element in enumerable
        .AfterFullIteration(() => Console.WriteLine("foo"))) {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
        if (element == 5) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -> still no foo because exception was thrown at the end
    Console.WriteLine("-------");
} catch { }

